# Realm Import after upgrading to 6.3.1

Tags: realm

I have a problem with Realm (Swift) after upgrading to Xcode 6.3.1
I used Ream with no problems earlier in my project and after upgrading I get "No such module Realm" error. Also I get "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" in RLMSupport.swift. I dunno what to do. I tried to clear everything, deleted derived data, installed latest Realm - nothing helps...

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions in the [Installation](https://realm.io/docs/cocoa/#installation) section of Realm's docs?

Here's a short screencast going through those same steps in a new Swift project in Xcode 6.3.1, in case one of those steps aren't clear: http://youtu.be/nm5DnXZxUMQ

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment and for video! But I did exactly the same. After another day of suffering... I decided to rename my project, so to remove  spaces from folder name. I dunno why, but after that, all errors gone and I've compiled it successfully. Can't understand why everything worked ok before this upgrade... But anyway - if anyone will face same problem - first of all, have a look at jpsim video, after (if  no results) - check spaces in your project name.